# Laravel 4.1 WhereIn w/ Many to Many Relation and Conditionals?

Tags: php, sql, orm, laravel, eloquent

I am working on an application where part of it needs to search through a number of different fields on the same model with AND - AKA find age `whereBetween $from` and `$to` AND where gender is `$gender`.  Where I am getting lost is this model has a many to many relationship with Category and I need to filter by category in the same query.  I am trying to do this in one query because it needs to be pretty fast.

Here is what I have so far:

```
    $categories = Input::get('categories');

    $query = Program::with('categories')->whereIn('category', $categories)->query();

    if ($ages = Input::get('ages')) {
        $query->whereBetween('age',array($from,$to));
    }

    if ($gender = Input::get('gender')) {
        $query->where('gender','like', $gender);
    }
    // Executes the query and fetches it's results
    $programs = $query->get();
```

I have put this together from so many different sources that I would like to know if this even works, or if it is the most efficient method possible. There is of course a table `programs`, a table `categories`, and a table `program_category` with columns `id`, `program_id`,  and `category_id`.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, in the end figured it out:

```
$query = Program::whereHas('categories', function($q) use ($categories)
    {
        $q->whereIn('categories.id', $categories);
    });
```

`'categories'` is the name of the relationship function on my Program model.  `$categories` is my array of category ids.  Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 0):

This will work if fields are available in the right table as you queried for and you may write it like this:

```
$categories = Input::get('categories');
$query = Program::with('categories')->whereIn('category', $categories);
// declare $from and $to if not available in the current scope
if ($ages = Input::get('ages')) $query->whereBetween('age', array($from,$to));
if ($gender = Input::get('gender')) $query->where('gender', $gender);

// Executes the query and fetches it's results
$programs = $query->get();
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm going to try this now...  will follow up.

Comment: No this didn't work, my fault for not explaining fully though.  Category is it's own model, and this model Program has a many to many relationship with it.  I am trying to filter programs by the category ids from an input array from checkboxes.  Those category ids are on the category model.  So I need to query the programs that are in the requested categories, then filter by the other inputs.

Comment: I think that this kind of thing is what I need to do, but I have no idea what I'm doing:  `$query = Program::whereHas('category', function($q) use ($categories)
  {
      $q->whereIn('category', $categories);
  });`